# How to display designation details along with number of employees for each branch?

Tags: mysql, sql

from hrm_personal_information(designation,branch) table how to get details of each designation (DESG_ID id, DESG_NAME) and each branch(BRANCH_ID,BRANCH_NAME) along with number of employees for each designation and each branch

Output is

```
SL. Designation Dhaka   Barisal  Jamalpur   Naogaon
1   Directors    10       2         3        2
2   Doctor        5       6         5        8
3   Staff Nurse   3       5         6        8
4   Nurse         3       5         9        7
5   Auxiliary Nurse       6         7        8
6   Counselor     2       5         8        9
7   Call Center   9       9         6        4
8   Optometrist   6       0         3        5
9   Cook          6       1         2        6

Total            46      47        47       60

Grand Total     200
```

Comment: Where do we get employees from ?

Comment: hrm_personal_information table

Comment: What column means employee?

Comment: designation column from hrm_personal_information